# styling two jquery-ui tooltips

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I use tooltips for displaying hints and displaying errors on a website, e.g.:

```
<span class="help">
<a title="hint for inputfield" href="javascript:void(0);">?</a>
</span>

<span class="error">
<a title="Please fill out!" href="javascript:void(0);">!!!</a>
</span>
```

I activate the tooltips with:

```
$( document ).tooltip();
```

In case of error I want to style the tooltip with a red border. I only found a way to style the tooltip global:
https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style
But how can I use two different styled tooltips on one single page?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a Fiddle, so we can play with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add a custom class to your error tooltip using tooltipClass property.

**HTML**

```
<span class="help">
    <a title="hint for inputfield" href="javascript:void(0);">?</a>
</span>

<span class="error">
    <a title="Please fill out!" href="javascript:void(0);">!!!</a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.error-style {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".help").tooltip();
$(".error").tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "error-style"
})
```

Here is the fiddle I have setup for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/t1h3werd/

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was quite simple... didn't realize that it's possible to treat the tooltip seperatly.